# Could not resolve com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

This error appears in most photo editing applications
I closed offline gradel mode and it didn't work
Knowing that the application was in the past working without problems, and the problem appeared after updates to Android Studio
Tried versions 4.1.1. and 4.1.2. And the. 4.2.2

```
Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/crysis21/Android/com/hold1/keyboardheightprovider/0.0.9/keyboardheightprovider-0.0.9.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
    Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /Users/mohammad/Downloads/QueShot - AdmobAd/QueShot - Green


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/crysis21/Android/com/hold1/keyboardheightprovider/0.0.9/keyboardheightprovider-0.0.9.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/crysis21/Android/com/hold1/keyboardheightprovider/0.0.9/keyboardheightprovider-0.0.9.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in 1.0.3. there was a mistake in generated Gradle POM. update dependency in your project.

```
implementation 'ro.holdone:keyboardheightprovider:1.0.3'
```

Comment: How can I do an update and what is the number supposed to be now ؟؟

Answer (score 0):

I looked into KeyboardHeightProvider library and I saw that the package name is changed. You should update the package in app gradle.

```
implementation 'ro.holdone.keyboardHeightProvider:1.0.1'
```